Problem with locale at boot
I am running Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
I have a script which does:
locale >> /root/testlocal.txt

and is run by rc.local and this provides the following information
LANG=en_GB.utf8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_GB.utf8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_GB.utf8"
LC_TIME="en_GB.utf8"
LC_COLLATE="en_GB.utf8"
LC_MONETARY="en_GB.utf8"
LC_MESSAGES=POSIX
LC_PAPER="en_GB.utf8"
LC_NAME="en_GB.utf8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_GB.utf8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_GB.utf8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_GB.utf8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_GB.utf8"
LC_ALL=

notice that LANGUAGE is empty and LC_MESSAGES=POSIX
This is causing a webapp, which is also started by rc.local running on the machine to print $ and not £
When I run locale from root these are both set to en_GB.utf8.
The workround I have is to run a script at the top of rc.local which does:
update-locale LANGUAGE=en_GB.UTF-8 LC_MESSAGES="en_GB.UTF-8"

and this seems to solve it as does stopping and starting the apps manually.  Is there something which needs configuring to make this workround un-necessary please?
